# Numerical Identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Please can someone explain if this identity is correct:

|a| = $\sqrt{a^2} \ $

I thought it should be:

|a| = $(\sqrt{a})^2\ $

being that the former would produce an answer that is either positive or negative.

Thank you for your help.

PS: The full question was comparing say:

|2x|/|3y| with $(\sqrt{(-2x/3y)} )^2 \ $

Comment: $\sqrt{x}$ is always positive, when it is defined (for $x\ge 0$).

Comment: Yes, but the question does not state x >= 0. That is why I am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $\sqrt{x}$ is defined in $\mathbb{R}$ only for $x\ge 0$ and it's always positive:

the first is correct and the absolute value is necessary , e.g. $\sqrt{(-2)^2}=|-2|=2$

the second is redundant since the square root exists only if $a>0$

An answer to the PS. require a discussion of the sign of $x/y$. Can you do this?

Comment: Thanks a lot. I understand.

Comment: You are welcome !  don't forget to accept if you like :)

Comment: Sorry, I am new to formatting, I must have mistakenly put the minus outside the brackets. I have corrected it. Is this the discussion you had in mind?

Comment: We must have $-x/y >0$ and this is done if $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing the standard meaning of the square root symbol with a correct understanding of squares and square roots. There are in fact two solutions to the equation $x^2 = 9$. namely $3$ and $-3$. But the accepted *convention* is that $\sqrt{9} = 3$, not $\pm 3$.

Comment: Modded up; specifically, the symbol $\sqrt{9}$ is called the "principal square root" of 9.

Answer (score 0):

If we examine your suggestion, we would have:

$$|(-3)|=\left(\sqrt{-3}\right)^{2}=\left(\sqrt{3}i\right)^{2} = 3i^{2} = -3 \neq 3$$

Moreover, the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ operator is defined to be non-negative for all non-negative real arguments, so $\sqrt{x^{2}}$ does give us a well defined value $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.

In response to your comment that $x \geq 0$ is not stated, we must remember that $x^{2}:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{*}$, where $\mathbb{R}^{*}$ is the set of non-negative real numbers. And so the square-root operator in $\sqrt{x^{2}}$ only ever has a non-negative argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.